# How is the Y-plane seemingly moved further away?

Tags: css, 3d

If you look at this spinning [cube](http://www.paulrhayes.com/experiments/cube-3d/) you can see from the css that the sides start out all in the same location and then are pushed using CSS away from the center of the cube. For example one of the sides has....

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(200px);
```

The cube is then rotated by rotating the div that surrounds all of the sides. For example...

```
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(-90deg);
```

What I can't figure out is how the cube is spinning 'further' into the screen than the front of the screen if that makes any sense. When I try and do a spinning cube the front side of the cube ends up as if its in front of the screen. i.e. you can't see all of it; its too big. Its as if the cube is aligned on the screen's plane.

I'd have thought the cube in the demo would have a z-transformation but I can't find one.

Answer (score 1):

In the example have a look at the parent element `experiment`. It has a css property `perspective` set to 800px. This is like the distance of the camera to the scene which affect all children. The field of view is automatically calculated so that an element on the z position 0 always has the original size.

So if you move an element further than 800px in positive z direction it will be behind the camera.
In the example the front side of the cube is only moved 200px.